# Verification input field does not reset

Tags: flutter

I am trying to implement the SMS verification on the application.

Currently, the cursor moves to the next field when I input the previous field. It's working fine. But the other fields are also clickable.

I want unless and until the previous text field is filled, the cursor does not move to the second and also the next field is not clickable. Also when I click on the previous field it resets the next all field value.

How can I implement these, also want to reset the next field if the previous field is clicked.
There seems a bubble when I place the cursor in the text field as shown in the figure.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CodeGenerate extends StatefulWidget {
  const CodeGenerate({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CodeGenerate> createState() => _CodeGenerateState();
}

class _CodeGenerateState extends State<CodeGenerate> {
  late List<TextEditingController> controllers;
  late List<FocusNode> focusNodes;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controllers = List.generate(4, (index) => TextEditingController());
    focusNodes = List.generate(4, (index) => FocusNode());
    focusNodes[0].requestFocus();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    for (var controller in controllers) {
      controller.dispose();
    }
    for (var focusNode in focusNodes) {
      focusNode.dispose();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.grey[200],
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              const Text(
                'Varification code',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 16),
              const Text(
                'Please input the 4 digits code received in the message.',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 26),
              Row(
                children: List.generate(
                  4,
                  (index) => Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: 60,
                      height: 80,
                      child: Center(
                        child: TextField(
                          controller: controllers[index],
                          focusNode: focusNodes[index],
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            if (value.isNotEmpty && index < 3) {
                              FocusScope.of(context)
                                  .requestFocus(focusNodes[index + 1]);
                            }
                            if (value.isEmpty) {
                              for (var i = index + 1;
                                  i < focusNodes.length;
                                  i++) {
                                focusNodes[i].unfocus();
                              }
                            }
                          },
                          showCursor: false,
                          readOnly: false,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          maxLength: 1,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            counter: const Offstage(),
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                    width: 2, color: Colors.black12),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                    width: 2, color: Colors.purple),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing `onChanged` function and adding `onTap` function?

```
onTap: () {
    if (index > 0 && controllers[index - 1].text.isEmpty) {
        // Reset the next field if the previous field is clicked
        controllers[index].clear();
    }
},
onChanged: (value) {
    if (value.isNotEmpty && index < 3) {
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusNodes[index + 1]);
    }
},
```

[Edit]
Ok, let's try like this:

Add list for tracking if field is Filled:

```
late List<bool> isFilled;
```

And fill it with `false` values:

```
isFilled = List.generate(4, (index) => false);
```

Add function for resetting fields:

```
void resetNextFields(int index) {
   for (int i = index + 1; i < isFilled.length; i++) {
      controllers[i].clear();
      isFilled[i] = false;
   }
}
```

Then add this to `TextField`:

```
controller: controllers[index],
focusNode: focusNodes[index],
onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
        isFilled[index] = value.isNotEmpty;
        if (value.isNotEmpty && index < 3) {
             FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusNodes[index + 1]);
        }
        if (value.isEmpty) {
             for (var i = index + 1; i < focusNodes.length; i++) {
                  focusNodes[i].unfocus();
             }
             resetNextFields(index);
        }
    });
},
enabled: !isFilled[index]
```

Comment: thank you for the time and effort.
It doesnot disable the next field until the previous field is filled. Ontap did the trick though and it reset the next value.